# I am getting a heap memory issue while running DSBULK load

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I have unloaded more than 100 CSV files in a folder. When I try to load those files to cassandra using DSBULK load and specifying the the folder location of all these files, I get the below error

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "unVocity-parsers input reading thread"
```

I wanted to see if anyone else has faced it and how it has been resolved.

Comment: How large is the heap that you're using?

Comment: In the logs, it shows allocated is 1739 MB. Is it possible to mention a different value when running DSBULK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. You can pass any JVM option or system property to the dsbulk executable using the `DSBULK_JAVA_OPTS` env var. See [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/install/dsbulkInstall.html#Post-installrequirementsandrecommendations) for more. Set the allocated memory to a higher value if possible.
2. You can throttle dsbulk using the `-maxConcurrentQueries` option. Start with `-maxConcurrentQueries 1`; then raise the value to get the best throughput possible without hitting the OOM error. More on this [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/engineOptions.html#engineOptions__dsbulkEngineOptionsMaxConcurrentQueries).

Comment: Thanks, i am following #2 and it is working.